# Combinatorics Problem (Getting off a elevator)

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

In how many $3$ males and $2$ females can get down from a lift in a building, having $5$ floors , such that at any floor, a lone pair of male and female is not allowed$?$

My attempt:

Since there are $5$ floors for any person to get off onto total ways would be $5^5$.

To construct a lone pair, one has $3$ choices for the male and $2$ choices for the female ,In total $\frac{3\cdot2}{2}$ ways (ignoring order).
And the resulting $2$ males and $1$ female and a pair have $5\cdot4^3$ ways.(Since other people can't get off at the floor the pair leaves.)

But we would have overcounted when there would be $2$ pairs which can get off in $5\cdot4\cdot3$ ways ($2$ pairs and one male). And we construct this in $\frac{3\cdot2}{2}$ for first pair and $\frac{2\cdot1}{2}$ for second pair, totalling $4$ ways.

So the answer should be $5^5-3\cdot5\cdot4^3+4\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$

But this is completely wrong and the correct answer is $1973$.

Could anybody point out mistakes in my counting method and suggest an appropriate way to proceed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please provide more context or at least explanation on what's going on. 1. On the 5th floor 3m+2f enter the lift, right? 2. Anyone can get out of the lift anywhere, unless 1f+1m left in the lift, right? 3. Are there any other constraints, like someone may enter not on the 5th floor? 4. Do the lift go only downwards? 5. Are the people distingushable? (there would be $32^4$ ways to exit the elevator at most then, not $5^5$) Thanks. I'd try recursion from the 1st floor.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: If each of $5$ distinguishable people can get off on any of $5$ floors, the number of unrestricted possibilities is $5^5$.

Comment: You can’t ignore the order when choosing a male and a female. You should have $3\cdot 2$ instead of $\frac{3\cdot 2}{2}$.

Comment: @user35508 the argument that "a pair leaves" or "gets off" doesn't make sense to me, it may "split" as well. The restriction is "in a moment of time there are no lonely pair inside the elevator" but it isn't said that a pair should leave at one. Thanks. Consider the python simulation with the value of $1973$ in the comments of the Brian M. Scott's answer too.

Comment: So there are at least two ways of reading the problem -- What is the number of ways of leaving a descending elevator in a $5$ floor building by $3$ men and $2$ women, entered on $5$th floor if 1) no different-sex pair can _leave off_ the elevator alone (with Brian M. Scott's answer of $1565$) **or** 2) no different-sex pair can _be left inside of_ the elevator alone (with the answer of $1973$ with formerly mentioned python simulation)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: Except that I get a much smaller figure than you when I use your interpretation. I’m deleting my answer until we can resolve the substantial remaining differences in our calculations for that interpretation.

Comment: You shouldn't delete it IMHO, because it contains the logic of considering **only** `mf` left alone inside the elevator **illegal** (no matter which pairs or singletons leave off, a `mf` can leave off as well) in the added part which (logic) I'm lacking to produce an answer with the total value of $1973$. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for your bright ideas I can finally arrive at a full answer now (not without a [python simulation](https://tio.run/##ZZHfbsIgFMbv@xQkuyi4Wuc2l8WEqz2GMaaTg8PypwFq3IzP3gGtViNpCP3O@X7nHGh@/Y/Rb5@N7TqhGmM9Eh6sN0a6jFuj0NZICVsvjHZoyGDAq1Z6Jra@@DKtDobM0ZeM0ZsIFtqTjG0eNW4s2iGhx0plYw1rQ9xWegd4QQoLDVSeLsgyQ2HJO4qDQIlyJOlCRBboVoGtPODd4Em@lViXFWNY94YjDd5rlRGSEL38Xkzn4buBHKc0cq7/gqPUxjA6zjlXSuWr/Tqx9pF1JITSU67y5bzIedjPIy8utgnEZzq/E78tVHVSQDoYDe42ka3Cs/yBjoNcOpCgsSDjJLI8VLIFh0lsto@SMly3ChJJdRsb3gI7MhxO9fIwm33M6snkNXHq4hBJbHOxnUn21Ocy0nX/) of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it's inclusion-exclusion principle in the end, but not that way.
I will write down the solution for the answer of $1973$, where the unacceptable ways (out of total unrestricted $5^5$) are *only* when a man stays with a woman alone in the elevator on the $k$th floor and maybe below (this idea contributes to the deleted Brian M. Scott's answer and reads "we must also exclude all ways that have a man and a woman as the last two occupying the elevator, even if they get off on different floors").
We can choose the two ones left in $2\cdot 3$ ways and the floors they get off in $k^2$ ways. So let's say all the left off people except the couple left off on $5$th to $(k+1)$th floors inclusive and $k$th is the first floor, counting top to bottom, where a man and a women left alone.
It's clear that the total number of ways that $3$ distingushable people can leave off on $5-k$ floors is $(5-k)^3$ but we should exclude the cases when all of them left exactly before (i.e. upper than) $(k+1)$th floor, so **now** we apply the incusion-exclusion principle to get $1^3$ for $k=4$, $2^3-1^3=7$ for $k=3$, $3^3-2^3=19$ for $k=2$ and $4^3-3^3=37$ for $k=1$,
with the total number of excluded cases $6\sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}k^2((5-k)^3-(4-k)^3)=1152$ the answer is
$$3125-1152=1973.$$

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I understand now I was interpreting the problem the other way as mentioned in the comments and even solving that wrong. I think I can now compute the answer to both of them...Thanks a lot for you brilliant approach.